# Вычисление по формуле

Tags: python, python-3.x, математика

Задание есть, где нужно произвести расчет по формуле. Но нужно сделать все в стиле ооп, создать класс с методом , что принимает значения. Я с классами еще не работал, помогите гайдом толковым, где рассказывают про вычисление через классы или помогите с этим заданием

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Покажите вашу попытку решить, можно без классов. И вам подскажут как дальше действовать

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import math

class Calc:
    def __init__(self, a, b, x):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.x = x

    def y(self):
        op1 = math.pow(math.sin(math.pow(self.x * self.x + self.a, 2)), 3)
        op2 = math.sqrt(self.x / self.b)
        return op1 - op2

    def z(self):
        op1 = self.x * self.x / self.a
        op2 = math.cos(math.pow(self.x + self.b, 3))
        return op1 + op2

calc = Calc(1.1, 0.004, 0.2)
print(calc.y())
print(calc.z())
```